# spring security - why to not use the 'spring-security-redirect' parameter in login forms to redirect to a particular page

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, spring-3

By default, when the user submits the login form, and is authenticated, he is redirected to the last URL he wished to access, before he logged out (fetched from the **request cache**) or to the root URL. Additionally, if a '`spring-security-redirect`' parameter is found with the form submission request, we are redirected to the value of that parameter.

I wish to use this feature, but in [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105833-Login-success-URL-for-each-browser-tab#4) thread, **Luke Taylor** mentioned that it would be a security risk, and we should use an additional form field for that purpose, and then customize our LoginSuccessHandler to retrieve and use that form field as we wish.

I am not able to understand the security risk he mentioned, and the reason we should not use a feature that Spring Security has already provided, instead of using our own custom logic. My reasons for wanting to use the functionality are the same as that of the OP in the above thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Attack behinde is some kind of [Cross-Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) (CSRF-Attack)

If an Attacker (A) send an modified link to Some Person (B) and B have a short look at this link and see it is your application, he might click this link.

Person B enters his credentials and get looged in.

But now the redirect is executed, WITH THE CREDENTIALS OF THAT PERSON B!

So imagine you have an Application where each User can Spend some money by invoking http://yourApp/spendSomeMoney=100   -- (*The first fault in that application would be that this is a GET and not a POST*)

Now imagine (A) send (B) this link:
http://yourApp/login.jsp?spring-security-redirect=http://yourApp/spendSomeMoney=100

You see the problem.

*In general I would stongly recommend to use some CSRF protection filter, no matter I you use that redirect or not.*

Comment: Thanks. So I need to add a 'spring-security-redirect' hidden form field instead of adding it to the URL, and accept only POST requests from the user ?

Comment: Some people suggest this, because it makes it a bit harder to send the faked "link" to somebody else. Anyway it is still possible, to send somebody a Html page with an form and button that send the POST with the hidden field. -- Anyway use a CSRF protection filter, then your are a bit saver, because CSRF attackes can come form every other web page in the whole Internet!